# For scrapy/selenium is there a way to go back to a previous page?

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I essentially have a start_url that has my javascript search form and button, hence the need of selenium. I use selenium to select the appropriate items in my select box objects, and click the search button. The following page, I do some scrapy magic. However, now I want to go BACK to the original start_url and fill out a different object, etc. and repeat until no more.

Essentially, I have tried making a for-loop and trying to get the browser to go back to the original response.url, but somehow it crashed. I may try having a duplicate list of start_url's on the top for scrapy to parse through, but I'm not sure if that is the best approach. What can I do in my situation?

Comment: is it possible to just use driver.get("url of start page") ? or do you need a way back the way a user would do it?

Comment: I actually could just do that! I'm going to try that and the driver.back() method, both would answer my question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here the advice is to use **`driver.back()`** : https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#navigation-history-and-location

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly it! Based on my question, do you suggest a more efficient way to loop through all the entries, or would the best way to be simply go backwards?

Comment: This is a dead link. Please include the relevant content in your answer.

Comment: since @seba didn't update his answer (dead link). You can find the command in this page section 3.6 : http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#navigation-history-and-location

Answer (score 20):

The currently selected answer provides a link to an external site and that link is broken. The selenium docs talk about

```
driver.forward()
driver.back()
```

but those will sometimes fail, even if you explicitly use some wait functions.

I found a better solution. You can use the below command to navigate backwards.

```
driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: I found the "window.history.go(-2)" command helpful for those weird websites that just refresh when you click the back button instead of actually going back.

Comment: Thanks @user1610950 I see that the script `driver.execute_script("window.history.go(+1)")` happily navigates forwards reliably for me too.

Answer (score 3):

To move backwards and forwards in your browser’s history use

```
driver.forward()
driver.back()
```